# Is it possible to stream from Safari to Apple TV with a MacBook Pro late 2008 with OS X 10.9.5?

Tags: appletv, streaming

I have a MacBook Pro from late 2008 running OS X 10.9.5. Is it possible to stream contents, playing in Safari, to Apple TV?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the graphics card in your Mac doesn't support AirPlay as its too old. I have the same problem with my mid-2010 MBP. You can see the list of supported hardware [here](https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT201343#requirements).

While there is software that will enable this functionality (like [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/)), I have found it severely under performs on older hardware and isn't really usable. You're welcome to give it a go though. :)